# Colored lines to form some kind of blanket

Tags: processing

So I'm trying to make a blanket with colored lines, but I can't seem to get to the result shown below...

My code first places a horizontal line and applies a color from an array, (The colors are correct) and than places a vertical line and applies a color from an array.

But I can't seem to get this result..

[image: Result I'm trying to make]

This is my code. Someone enlighten me?

```
float[][] vclrs = { //Array with color values for the vertical lines
  {220,31,24}, //Red
  {128,100,172}, //Purple
  {39,52,142}, //Blue
  {225,104,0}, //Beige
  {77,137,11}, //Green
  {83,188,188}, //Light Blue
};

float[][] hclrs = { //Array with color values for the horizontal lines
  {220,31,24}, //Red
  {187,167,212}, //Purple
  {39,52,142}, //Blue
  {244,198,149}, //Beige
  {77,137,11}, //Green
  {183,207,209}, //Light Blue
};

int controller = 8; //Width of the line and distance between the lines
int hlinedistance = controller; //Horizontal distance to place the next line
int vlinedistance = controller; //Vertical distance to place the next line

void setup() {
   size(576,480);
   background(255);
   strokeWeight(controller); //Stroke of the controller
}

void draw() {
  for(int i=0;i<6;i=i+1) {

      stroke(vclrs[i][0], vclrs[i][1], vclrs[i][2]);
      line(vlinedistance, 0, vlinedistance, displayHeight);
      vlinedistance = vlinedistance + (controller + controller);

      line(0, hlinedistance, displayWidth, hlinedistance);
      stroke(hclrs[i][0], hclrs[i][1], hclrs[i][2]);
      hlinedistance = hlinedistance + (controller + controller);

    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to think harder about the order the lines are drawn in your example image. Which lines are drawn first? Which are drawn last?

Comment: Is there a way to change the order of the lines after they are drawn? Or is it only possible to draw the lines in the correct order the first time?

Comment: You could *maybe* try something clever with the Z-order and OpenGL rendering, but that's way more work than just sitting down and trying to figure out the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about not clearing up the details (it is quite late now, but better now then never) and I didn't want to be offensive in any way.
As in every programming language the code gets viewed from top to bottom, so the lines are getting laid from top to bottom.

```
stroke(255, 0, 0); //red
line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
stroke(0, 255, 0); //green
line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

In this code snippet the red line gets drawn first and then the green line gets laid over the red line. So you end up only viewing the green line. In your example you have 4 layers of lines.

1. Group 1 of vertical lines.
2. Group 1 of horizontal lines.
3. Group 2 of vertical lines.
4. Group 2 of horizontal lines.

Every of these 4 groups has different colors stored inside them. In my solution you have the different strokes as follows:

1. vclrs = colors of vertical group 1
2. hclrs = colors of horizontal group 1
3. vclrs2 = colors of vertical group 2
4. hclrs2 = colors of horizontal group 2

We also use strokeCap(PROJECT); to make the lines edgy. To increase the lines width we use strokeWeight(width);

In the drawing part we now write these 4 for-loops, which switch up the colors accordingly using modulo 3 --> Hence you have 3 different colors per group. Modulo being the array of the color to choose from.
All of these 4 for loops are a little different since they have different positions involved, i'm sure you can understand the details there.

Here is your code modified to match up your result.
I hope this helps:

```
float[][] vclrs = { //Array with color values for the vertical lines
   {220,31,24}, //Red
   {128,100,172}, //Purple
   {39,52,142}, //Blue
 };

float[][] vclrs2 =
{
  {225,104,0}, //Beige
  {77,137,11}, //Green
  {83,188,188}, //Light Blue
};

float[][] hclrs = { //Array with color values for the horizontal lines
  {220,31,24}, //Red
  {187,167,212}, //Purple
  {39,52,142}, //Blue
};
float[][] hclrs2 = 
{
  {244,198,149}, //Beige
  {77,137,11}, //Green
  {183,207,209}, //Light Blue
};

int controller = 30; //Width of the line and distance between the lines

void setup() {
   size(576,480);
   background(255);
   strokeCap(PROJECT);
   strokeWeight(controller / 2); //Stroke of the controller
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(controller / 4, controller / 4);
  for(int i = 0; i < displayHeight / (3 * controller); i++) {
      stroke(vclrs[i % 3][0], vclrs[i % 3][1], vclrs[i % 3][2]);
      line((i * 2 * controller), 0, (i * 2 * controller), displayHeight);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < displayWidth / (3 * controller); i++) {
      stroke(hclrs[i % 3][0], hclrs[i % 3][1], hclrs[i % 3][2]);
      line(0, (i * 2 * controller), displayWidth, (i * 2 * controller));
  }

    for(int i = 0; i < displayHeight / (3 * controller); i++)
  {
      stroke(vclrs2[i % 3][0], vclrs2[i % 3][1], vclrs2[i % 3][2]);
      line((i * 2 * controller + controller), 0, (i * 2 * controller + controller), displayHeight);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < displayWidth / (3 * controller); i++)
  {
      stroke(hclrs2[i % 3][0], hclrs2[i % 3][1], hclrs2[i % 3][2]);
      line(0, (i * 2 * controller + controller), displayWidth, (i * 2 * controller + controller));
  }
  popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Even if this answer solves the problem, it is of low quality. It says nothing about _how_ you solved the problem, or about what the OP did wrong.

Comment: I tried a lot of things, but I couldn't get the result as shown above. Posting the code which results in the result I wanted does not help me at all. And for the 'lazy' part, it's quite offensive. I am new to Processing and have no clue what your code actually does. So no thank you from me, because this doesn't help me at all or motivates me..